# Machine Learning Geographical Data with NaNs

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I have some features (physical properties related to geographical etc. of the Earth), I have a target that I'd like to predict. Sometimes this target is covered with clouds so I cannot see its actual value.

Therefore at a single timestep I see a 2D target (latitude by longitude), sometimes there are NaN values corresponding to clouds (mostly, but not entirely). If I discard data over the whole area when there is any cloud I will be losing a lot of data, and also cherry-picking only sunny days.

Sometimes the satellite fails and there are NaN values for the whole day.

These issues are essentially only for the target - the features are essentially 'full data'.

I would like to have an MLP, LSTM or whatever other NN (say) that is capable of dealing with these NaN values. I do not know if the process I am trying to predict is sensitive to geographical location, so it could be the case that I can use one NN for all locations for this single target, or whether I would need e.g. if it is a 10x10 grid, to have 10x10 activation functions at the output layer. Either way I am unsure how to deal with this as backpropagation of NaNs at 'random' times and locations in the target data seems to be something that can't be calculated/done.

I assume this is not an uncommon problem, but can't find much on it. Does anyone know how to deal with NaNs in this situation?